# Poincaré Recurrence Theorem in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, phase-space, ergodicity, poincare-recurrence

The recurrence theorem of Poincaré tells us that EVERY open set in the phase space will be crossed infinitely often. It doesnt matter if the open set is a neighbourhood of the initial data set or not.

In Quantum Mechanics there is a recurrence theorem as well. It states that any system will return arbitarily close to its INITIAL state.
(See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem)

Is it also true in Quantum Mechanics, that the system will become arbitarily close to EVERY normed state in the Hilbert Space? Or is this in QM only true for the initial state?

Comment: Take a Hamiltonian with spectrum $H z_i = E_i z_i$ and $z(t=0)= a_1 z_1+a_2 z_2 $, evolve $z(t)$ in time. You will never get close to, say the state $z_7$ but you'll come back to $z(t=0)$ for sufficiently long times.

Answer (score 1):

The compacity of the “available region” in phase space is an important assumption for the classical case. Take for example the a free particle given by the Hamiltonian:
$$
H=\frac{p^2}{2}
$$
You don’t have recurrence since the trajectories go to infinity. In the case of the harmonic oscillator of Hamiltonian:
$$
H=\frac{p^2+x^2}{2}
$$
things work again since trajectories are constrained in energy level sets which are circles. You therefore need to check that the trajectory is constrained in a compact region.

This leads to a second caveat. You forgot the condition that the open set must be crossed at least once. You therefore have two cases, either it is never crossed, either it is crossed an infinite number of times.

Given an initial condition, it is not obvious to characterize the states that will be reached arbitrarily closely. An elementary necessary characterization of these states is to check whether the integrals of motions are the same as given by the initial condition. In the example of the harmonic oscillator, in which case you need only consider energy, if you start at a given energy, you are forced to stay in that energy level set, so an open set consisting only of high energy states is unattainable.

However, it is not obvious that should be sufficient. With a bit of work, this turns out to be case (almost surely) for [integrable systems](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%E2%80%93Arnold_theorem). In general, this is hard to prove and may not even be correct.

This discussion has its analogues in QM. Heuristically, the compacity of the accessible space is “equivalent” to the discreteness of the energy spectrum of the initial state. In particular, this is the case when the evolution of the state is restricted to a finite dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Once again, you have the dichotomy: either the state is reached arbitrarily closely an infinite number of times, either it is not even once.

To characterize the former case, a starting point would be to examine the smallest direct sum of energy eigenspaces containing the initial condition. However, you need to be careful with degeneracies. Since two energy eigenstates evolve in phase, the time evolution only explores a line in the energy eigenspace.

Hope this helps.